# Улучшение страницы справки «Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Заголовок: «What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?»
Ссылка не текущую версию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

---

Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about. Basic use of the site, including asking questions, answering, and suggesting edits, does not require any reputation at all. But the more reputation you earn, the more [privileges](/privileges) you gain.

The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and useful answers. Votes on these posts cause you to gain (or sometimes lose) reputation. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation.

You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. [Bounty awards](/helpcenter/bounty), [accepted answers](/helpcenter/accepted-answer), and [association bonuses](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

**You gain reputation when:**

- question is voted up: +5
- answer is voted up: +10
- answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
- suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
- bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
- one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount ([see more details about how bounties work](/helpcenter/bounty))
- site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)
- example you contributed to is voted up: +5
- proposed change is approved: +2
- first time an answer that cites documentation you contributed to is upvoted: +5

If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

**You lose reputation when:**

- your question is voted down: −2
- your answer is voted down: −2
- you vote down an answer: −1
- you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
- one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1. Accepting your own answer does not increase your reputation. Deleted posts do not affect reputation, for voters, authors or anyone else involved, in [most cases](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/). If a user reverses a vote, the corresponding reputation loss or gain will be reversed as well. Vote reversal as a result of voting fraud will also return lost or gained reputation.

At the high end of this reputation spectrum there is little difference between users with high reputation and ♦ moderators. That is intentional. We don’t run this site. The community does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок: «Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?»

---

Репутация – это упрощенная мера того, насколько вам доверяет сообщество; чтобы ее заработать, требуется убедить других участников в правильности и достоверности изложенной вами информации. Основные действия на сайте, включая создание вопросов, ответов и предложение правок, не зависят от репутации. Но чем выше репутация, тем больше у вас [привилегий](/help/privileges).

Основной способ заработать репутацию – это создавать хорошие вопросы и полезные ответы. Голоса за эти сообщения повышают или понижают вашу репутацию. Обратите внимание, что сообщения, помеченные как «общие вопросы» не влияют на репутацию.

В день можно заработать до 200 баллов репутации любым сочетанием приведенных ниже действий. [Конкурсы](/help/bounty), [принятые ответы](/help/accepted-answer) и [бонусы за подключения к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) не ограничены дневным пределом репутации.

#### Репутация повышается в следующих случаях:

- за вопрос был отдан один голос: +5;
- за ответ был отдан один голос: +10;
- если ваш ответ «принят»: +15 (а также +2 балла участнику, который принял ответ);
- за принятую предложенную вами правку: +2 (всего до +1000 на одного участника);
- ваш ответ получает вознаграждение: + полная сумма вознаграждения;
- один из ваших ответов автоматически получает вознаграждение: + половина от суммы вознаграждения (см. [более подробное описание принципа работы системы вознаграждений](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty));
- бонус за подключение к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов: +100 для каждого сайта (выдается только один раз для каждого сайта).

Если вы опытный пользователь сети Stack Exchange с репутацией 200 или более хотя бы на одном из сайтов, вы получите стартовый бонус +100 к репутации на других сайтах, что позволит вам обойти ограничения для новых участников. Это произойдет автоматически на всех текущих сайтах Stack Exchange, где у вас есть учетная запись, и на любых других сайтах Stack Exchange в момент, когда вы вводите свои учетные данные.

#### Репутация понижается в следующих случаях:

- против вашего вопроса был отдан один голос: −2;
- против вашего ответа был отдан один голос: −2;
- вы проголосовали против ответа: −1;
- вы предложили вознаграждение за вопрос: − полная сумма вознаграждения;
- одно из ваших сообщений получает 6 тревог за спам или агрессию: −100.

Все участники начинают с 1 баллом репутации. Репутация не может опуститься ниже 1. Принятие своего ответа на собственный вопрос не повышает репутацию. Если участник отзывает голос, соответствующее повышение или понижение репутации также отменяется. Репутация, приобретенная в результате мошеннических действий с голосованием, аннулируется.

Между участниками с достаточно высокой репутацией и ♦ модераторами практически нет различий. И это не случайно, ведь сообществом должны управлять именно его участники.